# How do I delete records saved with collection_select in Rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

My goal is to be able to update a saved record when items are de-selected from a collection_select (and then that record is resubmitted.) Thanks in advance for your help!

**Details**

I've got a form for Newsavedmaps. Newsavedmaps can have many waypoints. Users can select waypoints in a collection_select, and when they save the Newsavedmap, these waypoints are saved to their own database table.

The problem: when users open the Newsavedmap they've saved, I want them to be able to de-select a waypoint. When they save the Newsavedmap again, I want the de-selected waypoint to be deleted.

This is a Rails 2.3X app I'm maintaining, which is why the collection_select uses a different format below.

**Model**

```
class Newsavedmap < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :itinerary
  has_many :waypoints, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :waypoints, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:waypointaddress].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

**View**

```
    <% form_for @newsavedmap, :html => { :id => 'createaMap' } do |f| %>
      <%= f.error_messages %>               
      <%= f.text_field :name, {:id=>"savemap_name", :size=>30 }%></p>

      <%= collection_select :waypoints, :waypointaddress, @newsavedmap.waypoints, :waypointaddress, :waypointaddress, {}, { :multiple => true, :class => "mobile-waypoints-remove", :id =>"waypoints" } %>

    <% end %>
```

**Newsavedmaps Controller**

```
def create
  @newsavedmap = Newsavedmap.new(params[:newsavedmap])
  waypoint = @newsavedmap.waypoints.build

  respond_to do |format|
    if @newsavedmap.save
      flash[:notice] = 'The new map was successfully created.'
      format.html { redirect_to "MYURL"}
      format.xml  { render :xml => @newsavedmap, :status => :created, :location => @newsavedmap }
    else
      format.html { render :action => "new" }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @newsavedmap.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end


def update
  @newsavedmap = Newsavedmap.find(params[:id])

  if @newsavedmap.itinerary.user_id == current_user.id
    respond_to do |format|
      if @newsavedmap.update_attributes(params[:newsavedmap])
        flash[:notice] = 'Newsavedmap was successfully updated.'
        format.html { redirect_to "MYURL" }
        format.xml  { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @newsavedmap.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  else
    redirect_to '/'
  end
end
```

**Params when creating new record**

Parameters: {"newsavedmap"=>{"name"=>"Name of my map", OTHER FIELDS NOT SHOWN ABOVE, "waypoints"=>{"waypointaddress"=>["1600 Pennsylvania Ave NW, Washington, DC 20500", "350 5th Ave, New York, NY 10118"]}}

Comment: Could you post params which come from your form

Comment: Added. As it turns out, the above is creating a single new, empty record in the waypoints database (rather than two waypoint records with one address each.) I think that's because my controller is telling the form to build a waypoint each time there's a new Newsavedmap, but it's completely ignoring the data. Any ideas?

Comment: about empty record in DB: you are right. In method `create` you initialize a new `@newsavedmap` from params, then build a new one `waypoints` and save @newsavedmap - this saves @newsavedmap and built waypoints. Remove this building for waypoints in method create

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in correctly built form (and params which come from it).

I suggest to

1. look at gem [cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) or [nested_form](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form)
2. add `waypoints_attributes` to attr_accessible
3. implement helpers from gem (from point #1) in your form

And Rails magic should done other job

Comment: Thanks for your response, gotva. Unfortunately, I can't rely on the gems. But I did have a question: is it necessary anyway for me to include attr_accessible , and if so, where does it go?

Comment: about gems: I think it will be dificult to build the form correctly for `accept_nested_attributes` without gems. About `attr_accessible`: no it is not necessary but in this case you should care about assigning params manually, smth like this @newsavedmap.waypoints_attributes = params[:newsavedmap][:waypoints_attributes]. If you want to add `attr_accessible` add it to model `Newsavedmap` (and remember that if no attr_accessible is set then all attributes are in this list by default)

Comment: Thanks, Gotva! I'll skip the attr_accessible. I read your comment, but there's got to be a way to add and remove records with the collection_select without gems using nested forms, right? Any ideas?

Comment: You should to build form that can build and pass to controller params with special structure. [There is](https://gist.github.com/gotva/6662119) an example for similar periods_attributes. I doubt that `collection_select` can build such parameters. Maybe I am wrong and Rails 2.3 has a way to build params for accept_nested_attributes. PS could you explain why you don't want to use gem (I believe that some versions of them work with Rails 2.3)

Answer (score 0):

Another variant (without using gems) (**I think much more difficult way!**)

You can remove `accept_nested_attributes` at all and work with your params directly. But in this case you should manage manually all process: correct inserting records, correct destroying them.

In your case it should smth like this (it is not tested!). The example based on your params which posted in the question.

```
def create
  # delete params 'waypoints' it will be manage manually
  waypoints = params[:newsavedmap].delete(:waypoints)
  @newsavedmap = Newsavedmap.new(params[:newsavedmap])
  waypoints.each do |waypoint|
    @newsavedmap.waypoints.build(:waypointaddress => waypoint)
  end
  if @newsavedmap.save
    ...
  end
end
```

the main troubles will be in method `update`

```
def update
  # delete params 'waypoints' it will be manage manually
  waypoints = params[:newsavedmap].delete(:waypoints)

  # find and setup attributes
  @newsavedmap = Newsavedmap.find(params[:id])
  @newsavedmap.attributes = params[:newsavedmap]

  # TROUBLES start here
  # destroy not checked (but existed in DB) waypoints
  existed_waypoints = @newsavedmap.waypoints
  existed_waypoint_addresses = existed_waypoints.map(&:waypointaddress)
  new_waypoints = []
  waypoints.each do |waypoint|
    if existed_waypoint_addresses.include?(waypoint)
      # existed waypoint was selected on the form
      # find it and add to new_waypoints
      new_waypoints << @newsavedmap.waypoints.find_by_waypointaddress(waypoint)
    else
      # new waypoint was selected on the form
      # build it and add to new_waypoints
      new_waypoints << @newsavedmap.waypoints.build(:waypointaddress => waypoint)
    end
  end
  # setup new records for waypoints
  @newsavedmap.waypoints = new_waypoints

  if @newsavedmap.save
    # destroy existed but not selected waypoints
    (existed_waypoints - new_waypoints).map(&:destroy)
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Gotva, I really appreciate the update. However, I'd like to work with nested forms here rather than trying to get around them. There's got to be a way to add and remove records with the collection_select, right?